# Removing deafult background of ImageButton in Android but keep onClick highlight

Tags: android, background, onclick

I have a few ImageButtons in my app and I'v removed the default grey background with

`android:background="@android:color/transparent"` or `android:background="@null"`

The problem is, it also removes the onClick highlight background (orange in API8 and blue in API16)

I'v read so many Q&A here, people are all suggesting to use `selector`.Instead of making another image for each of the buttons, I'd like to have a background color highlight only. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

solution: **programmatically**

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

// ...

btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
            // set background highlight color
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
        }
        if(event.getAction() == (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {
            // restore transparent
            btn.setBackgroundResource(
                getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

It isn't *that* simple, but does the job and saves me a lot of time making another image for each button while I don't really need fancy onclick styles.

Comment: how is your solution simpler than creating a selector and applying it to all buttons (especially when the background is either transparent or solid color)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really need to use a selector for this.

You can use colors for your backgrounds in your selectors, it doesn't need to be a PNG resource (just set the background to a color, instead of a drawable resource).

You will place this code in your drawable folder, with a specific name (like button_sel.xml).

Then you set this as the background to your button in your XML it would look like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/button_sel"
```

The selector would look something like this:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/ab_background"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/ab_background"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/ab_background_on"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/ab_background_on"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks Booger. I'm new to Android programming, and I thought I *had* to use an image in selector.

Answer (score 5):

There are only two attributes relevant in this case - `background` and `src`. If you want to use the same background for all image buttons (with color highlight), you need to add the part of background which changes from button to button to your image set by `src`, which is not too clean and neat (but of course you can do that if you want).

So I think the best here is to use selectors for background, as suggested by many users.

use the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I would'v accepted your answer if you had your *edited version* posted before Booger...

Comment: @user1643156 no problem with that :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so, you can search through the API to find the predefined selector for the ImageButton, than copy the code and alter the selector the way you need it. So you would create a custom ImageButton.

But I don't think there is an easy way, just like you wanted it with just changing a color

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem but now it has been solved. If you are using **`android:background="@null`** it will resulted of no background at all and no button pressed animation will be appeared to the user.

Just adding this line of code to make an image button become flashing upon clicked. This is the proper way to alert the user an image button has been clicked.

```
 android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground
```